# How to include both English and Telugu content in Latex where the majority of the content is English?

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia

I am trying to use `polyglossia` and `fontspec`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pothana2000}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{telugu}

\begin{document}
\begin{telugu} 
చేయి అనగా మానవులు, కోతులు మరియు లెమూర్లకు గల శరీరభాగమునకు వేళ్లు
కలబాహ్యంగము. కోలా చేతికి ఎదురెదురుగా వున్న రెండు బొటనవ్రేళ్లు వుంటాయి కాబట్టి దాని శరీరభాగాన్ని
కూడా చేయి లేక 'పా'లు అంటారు.
\end{telugu}
```

It works fine but I can't get English text in here. When put some English content it is not displayed at all. If have to get some English content, I need to use some new font family and the process is really convoluted. I would like the default script be English with whatever default font comes with the LaTeX class I use for a paper and have the Telugu script just for a small paragraph with the `Pothana2000` or any other nice font that I can use with XeLaTeX in Windows. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Pothana2000 has no character for the Latin Script. You should use it only for your Telugu parts. Here how you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\telugufont{Pothana2000}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{telugu}

\begin{document}

\hyphenpenalty=-4000

\kant[2]

\begin{telugu} 
చేయి అనగా మానవులు, కోతులు మరియు లెమూర్లకు గల శరీరభాగమునకు వేళ్లు
కలబాహ్యంగము. కోలా చేతికి ఎదురెదురుగా వున్న రెండు బొటనవ్రేళ్లు వుంటాయి కాబట్టి దాని శరీరభాగాన్ని
కూడా చేయి లేక 'పా'లు అంటారు.
\end{telugu}

\end{document}
```

The package `kantlipsum` is used to produce mock English text, while `\hyphenpenalty=-4000` serves to induce XeTeX to hyphenate more than usual: don't use them in your document.

Of course you can add

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{My Beatiful Font}
```

(where you'd use a real font name) for the English text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. The output of the Telugu text in the final pdf is actually not looking that good (it looks like in your output above) compared to what I got when I was using `Pothana2000` as the main font using `setmainfont`. I am not sure how I can show you the corrected pdf output.

Comment: Okay this fixed it: `\newfontfamily{\telugufont}[Script=Telugu]{Pothana2000}`. I just added `[Script=Telugu]` to the new font family definition. Thanks, again.